# .htaccess Redirect based on cookie value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like a very simple way to direct all users that do not have a particular cookie value. I have tried the following code, it redirects and then goes to my ISP's page not found splash page

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^user=(admin)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/login.php [R=301,L]
```

I do not have any other rules. I also only have just two pages on the server. It is redirected to login.php and then I get the following firefox error

```
    The page isn't redirecting properly.
    Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies
```

Comment: Do you have other rules in your htaccess ? When do you get a redirect and from where ? To where ? What's the url when not found ?

Comment: @JustinIurman I've have added to my question, thanks.

Comment: Ok you have an infinite loop. First, you shouldn't use permanent redirect (301) for that. You should just check if *cookie* `user` is equals to `admin` and if it's not then redirect (302: temporary) to `login.php`

Comment: I just tried that, it didn't work, thanks.

Comment: You have to clear your browser's cache before trying it. Your old rule is now in cache, you won't see the new behaviour

Comment: I reset safari and then tried again. It came up with an error about too many redirect loops. I don't think my rewrites are correct.

Comment: Only put this after `RewriteEngine On` directive: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user=admin [NC] RewriteRule ^ /login.php [R,L]`

Comment: I am getting the same error. I reset safari, open/closed it, still the same error. I think it has to do with the way i'm using `{HTTP_COOKIE}`

Comment: it is a loop to /admin since browser always send this cookie. Add a condition like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/admin [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some conditions to prevent the looping:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^user=(admin)$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 ^login\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/login.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem with this code also, thanks though.